# How would you test a program that's supposed to run long time?

Tags: testing

How would you test a program that's supposed to run long time?

In my project, the program is designed to keep running for years.  It's impossible for the QA guys to really test the program that long time.  Then what test strategy should I apply to guarantee that the program could really run for that long time?

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the good old halting problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: We'd really need some more information, such as why the system needs t run for *years*. Can you you test and verify individual components? Is it just a data persistence issue and the software can start and stop? etc...

Comment: Could you tell us more about the requirement to "run for years". Perhaps running the same "program" for years does not mean the same _process_ must be run for years? Also, tell us more about your target platform and language/libraries. Have you already implemented the program or you are just getting started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any point in time, as the program executes, the program could enter an invalid state that causes it to crash (which I guess is what you are really interested in). So you are really asking "how can I ensure my program has a low probability of entering an invalid state". Your test strategy will have to be thorough. You might want to consider focusing on testing the parts of the software that do error recovery, to ensure that an internally detected error does not cause a crash.

---

*Edit*

Let me explain further.

All long running programs essentially serve a sequence of inputs or requests, each of which creates a task to be processed. Once processed,  each task is discarded. You will want to ensure that a problem with one such task does not prevent processing of subsequent tasks, *even if* the problem with the task is due to a bug in the code for processing that task. In practice this means the server has some code for error recovery.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that I didn't accept any answer for this question. I read through all the answers and I think yours is the closest to what I want. Yeah,  it's impossible to prove the correctness of the system simply by running it long enough. But a good testing coverage can. Error recovery code is also essential for long running systems. Besides, I'm also thinking about using formal modeling method to mathematically verify, if needed, the correctness of the core parts of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Depends exactly what its supposed to be doing?

For example if you abstract all timer related things through an interface then you can "fake" the passage of time and run your application at say, 1,000,000 x speed. So if you ran a test for 1 min it would be as if you have tested it for 1,000,000 mins.

Of course this all depends on exactly what you're doing since perhaps the passage of time isn't what would cause your tests to actually require a long time to execute.

Answer (score 1):

1) unit testing -- If the components work properly, it is more likely that the overall program will work properly.

2) simplified integration tests -- Try running it on a small problem that won't take as long to run.

You can unit test higher-level components of your program by providing fake objects to do the lower-level work that would normally be too expensive to run.

Comment: This is true for any kind of program, it is not specific to a long running program.

Comment: @raedwald: Cato's answer is still pretty good advice.  If it won't pass these kinds of tests, it isn't likely to have long, stable runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

Test it for a shorter while. Usually a program will not run for years because of memory leaks and the like. If you don't have any leaks in a day or a week, then you will likely not have a leak in a year either.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to others, think what you expect the state of the software to be after years of running. Consider what will change and try to produce the same situation in shorter time. For example if you think database will grow and have tens of millions of entries after couple years, simulate the situation by adding those entries now and verify that system can still perform.